# Custom Sort on Group By Column SSRS / SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a sample data as below.

```
Key KeyName CustomerName  CID      Role

1   K1      Ram           C1       Main
1   K1      Laxman        C5       Child
2   K2      Shyam         C2       Main
3   K3      Ram           C1       Main
4   K4      Shyam Bothe   C2       Main 
5   K5      Berry         C3       Child
6   K6      Berry Ping    C3       Main
```

Here the same customer exist in multiple keys. I want to sort the duplicate customers in the order of their keys as below.

```
Key KeyName CustomerName  CID      Role

1   K1      Ram           C1       Main
1   K1      Laxman        C5       Child
3   K3      Ram           C1       Main
2   K2      Shyam         C2       Main
4   K4      Shyam Bothe   C2       Main 
5   K5      Berry         C3       Child
6   K6      Berry Ping    C3       Main
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Key, KeyName, CustomerName, CID, Role
from table
order by CID, KeyName asc;
```

Comment: This won't show the output in the order of duplicates by keys.

Comment: so you want customername to be sorted in order based on their key. in that case use order by CustomerName, Key.

Comment: In the output, you can see that CID "C1" exists in both Keys K1 and K3. Similarly, CID "C2" exists in both Keys K2 and K4. SO I need the output arranged in the order of customer occurrence in the Keys

Comment: use order by CID asc, KeyName asc;  here you no need to keep explicitly asc as by default the sort order will be asc. just for your understanding i kept asc.  you can even try and see the result by changing the sorting order. example: order by CID desc, KeyName asc;   just play with those orders and you will understand how this works.